# Master Page Format Change

Tags: 2013, development, css, asp.net, custom-masterpage

I am taking the plunge to change a master page format.  I am wanting for the text to appear in the middle of the page with a frame around the text.

Question. Does anyone know on how this can be done? Or is there a prefabricated master page that I can buy that will offer the same outcome?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hire me to do it if you are already interested in buying :).. That should be easy with a little CSS trick..

Comment: Arslan, I sent you email on hotmail address...please check

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of links explain steps on how to customize SharePoint 2013 master page. Please refer

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7GM6Fnz_H4
http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/158/Edit-existing-master-page-in-SharePoint-2013